# Source map error: Error: Invalid URL how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, image, firefox, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have next.js app using chakra ui styles . Its movie app and its fetching images from movie db.
When i open my site before image load I can see only ulr text for this img then after 1s image laodes. How to prevent this ?

And i get that error form firefox:

Source map error: Error: Invalid URL: webpack://[name]_[chunkhash]/webpack/bootstrap
Resource URL: http://127.0.0.1:3001/_next/static/development/dll/dll_01ec57fc9b90d43b98a8.js?ts=1574263926643
Source Map URL: dll_01ec57fc9b90d43b98a8.js.map

Comment: I ran into the same issue! Did you figure out the problem/solution or a workaround?

Comment: sadly not , but i keep trying ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to config [output.devtoolNamespace](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputdevtoolnamespace).

> This option determines the modules namespace used with the output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate. When not specified, it will default to the value of: output.library. It's used to prevent source file path collisions in sourcemaps when loading multiple libraries built with webpack.

If you use firefox to debug, you'd better config `output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate` to use `http://` instead of `webpack://`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and found out that there seems to be a bug concerning source maps and Firefox:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9471

Chrome does not show this problem...